# JWT Java library that provides multiple signatures

Tags: jwt

I am in one of the cases that needs signing a payload with multiple signatures, as case (2) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51443679/15649).

As a reminder, JWT is specified by [RFC7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519), in which signing is defined to use JSON Web Signature, JWS, [RFC7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515).

JWS/RFC7515 define the compact representation in [Section 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-7.1), which is widely implemented by libraries. But they also define the longer JWS JSON Serialization in [Section 7.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-7.2), which allows for multiple signatures of the payload.

The documentation at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) lists a plethora of Java libraries, but is there any of them that actually implements Section 7.2, with the multiple signatures?

Answer (score 0):

You can the bookstore

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>9.16</version>
        </dependency>
```

The following link shows how to make a signature with multiple private keys and then its corresponding validation

https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jws-json-multiple-signatures

https://8gwifi.org/jwkconvertfunctions.jsp

https://dzone.com/articles/json-message-signing-alternatives